# EF Core Transactions across multiple DbContexts vs Queue msg

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

What approach to use when storing/updating data across multiple DbContex'ts?
Performance comparison: and in which case to when use what:

```
 using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (var context1 = new ItemContext(userOptions))
            {
                context1.Items.Add(item);
                context1.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context2 = new OrderContext(orderOptions))
            {
                testOrder.ItemId = item.Id;
                context2.Orders.Add(testOrder);
                context2.SaveChanges();
            }

            if(testOrder.SunIsShining){
               using (var context1 = new ItemContext(itemOptions))
               {
                  item.SunIsShining= true;
                  context1.Items.Update(item);
                  context1.SaveChanges();
               }
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

A. The example above using Transaction scope and changing /updating records in between different Context's in the same physical server.

B. Use messages. For example after saving a user to db. Call messaging service that would insert info msg to a queue (item info records).
 Then an ItemOrderProcessingService would read that queue say every 10s taking all new records in it.
 And in batches would create orders, perhaps if needed update some item statuses too in the item table also in batches. 
 (have logic to rollback changes if needed)

When to use which approach, what are the benefits/ drawbacks? f.e. If we have ~2k transactions a day which is rather low..
How many transactions per day one should one have to use B. queue approach?

Comment: Why do you use several db contexts? Do you have several databases?

Comment: @Serhii_Voichyk The db is only one. But the separate contexts represent code separation using DDD. So new Domain is a separate Db context which is a basically a Table.

Comment: @Greed ok, I got but my opinion hasn't changed - for a small amount of users and transactions it would be much simpler to use TransactionScope rather than messaging because implementation and maintaining requires more effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely different approaches. When you use transaction it's much simpler to do a rollback for all contexts. It will take some time in the message-based system until your messages will be handled by all services and also you should handle service fail and check data consistency

Message-based requires more effort from the team to maintain and support microservices handling messages and for a small application, like yours, using monolith application is quite ok.